# Eval ConnectionString using public property from code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, eval

Perhaps a silly question, but here goes nothing :)

Up to now, I've been using html markup for `asp:SqlDataSource`, when setting the connection string, like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsMyDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ActualConnStringNameFromWebConfig %>"
                SelectCommand="select something from Table">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Note the classic form: `ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ActualConnStringNameFromWebConfig %>"`

But how can I set (if possible) the connection string for the same `asp:SqlDataSource`, like this :

```
ConnectionString="<%# ConnectionStrings:Eval("MyCodeBehindString") %>"
```

Where in my code behind I have something like this:

```
public partial class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public const string MyCodeBehindString = "ActualConnStringNameFromWebConfig";
    //rest of code
}
```

Web Config section:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <remove name="ActualConnStringNameFromWebConfig" />
    <add name="ActualConnStringNameFromWebConfig" connectionString="Data Source=(localhost);Initial Catalog=MyDB;Persist Security Info=True; bla bla   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

When I do use it like this, I get an error saying the Server tag is not well formed...

Answer (score 0):

You can read a connection string like that from the `web.config`. In order for you to read it, you'll have to do something like

```
string MyCodeBehindString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ActualConnStringNameFromWebConfig"].ConnectionString;
```

Ensure you add the following reference `using System.Configuration;`

I would recommend working all your `Sql` stuff out in the code behind.

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection(MyCodeBehindString))
{
 //Do Some work  
}
```

To ensure that connections are always closed, open the connection inside of a `using` block, as shown in the code fragment above. Doing so ensures that the connection is automatically closed when the code exits the block.

Comment: Hi Izzy, I don't think you understood my question. I was asking if there is any way I could use one of the public properties from the code behind via Eval() function in the connection string of the asp:SqlDataSource.

Answer (score 0):

In your code behind set a variable containing the actual connections string (note the protected access modifier so it's a accessible in the aspx):

**aspx.cs:**

```
protected string MyCodeBehindString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ActualConnStringNameFromWebConfig"].ConnectionString;
```

**aspx:**

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsMyDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%= MyCodeBehindString %>"
    SelectCommand="select something from Table">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: I did as you said, but I'm getting this error now: 
Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
Source Error: 
 An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  
[InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.PermissionDemand()

Comment: Sorry I think it's the way I've called the variable in the aspx -- this works with <%= MyCodeBehindString %> for straight up dumping out, but within this context try wiith <%# MyCodeBehindString %>

Comment: Did it help with # rather than = ?

Comment: Tried every possible combination, it's not working and I'm almost certain now that this is impossible to achieve ( specially after re-reading this article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/976112 ). Anyway, I will set my connection string for the sqldatasource from code-behind and call it a day :) Thanks anyway!